# How I show $h^k(t)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

$$
\hat{h}^k(s) = \big[1-\theta-\theta\tanh(a\sqrt s)\coth(b\sqrt s)\big]^k\hat{h}^0(s)
$$ is true for $k=1,2, \ldots$ and $a>b$, where $s$ is Laplace variable and the relation is after taking Laplace transform and $0<\theta<1$. Now how I show $h^k(t)$ converges?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are various modes of convergence, e.g. pointwise convergence, convergence in $L^p$.

Comment: @ George Dewhirst , no $k$ is the power of whole in the bracket. convergence in $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: Then differentiate with respect to $s$ and find the maximum for each fixed $k$, then looked at the convergence of the maximum.

Comment: its getting ugly, not  getting something useful by derivative.